# Upload an Object Using the AWS SDK for Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am using the following code from AWS documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

And i have used the following jars :
[image: Jars used]

And i am getting the following error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>       at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:58)
>       at UploadObject.main(UploadObject.java:17)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 2 more

Any help would be appreciated for the same. I have tried adding the common logging jars but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there are quite a few third-party library's required for AWS to work. The ones below are the extras packaged with the SDK download. I seem to remember there being one missing though so let me know if this doesn't work and i'll check my dependencys.

All of these can be found in '\aws-java-sdk-1.9.1\third-party'

> aspectj-1.6
>
> commons-codec-1.6
>
> commons-logging-1.1.3
>
> freemarker-2.3.1.8
>
> httpcomponents-client-4.3
>
> jackson-annotations-2.3.0
>
> jackson-core-2.3.2
>
> jackson-databind-2.3.2
>
> javax-mail-1.4.6
>
> joda-time-2.2
>
> spring-3.0

Comment: That's great, there is very little mention of the extra library's so i see quite a few people run into the same issue. Would you mind accepting my answer by giving it the check mark please.